# Maven location for JCA Connector 1.6

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, maven-2

Does anyone know if the API for the Java EE Connector version 1.6 is located in some Maven Repository? As I can't seem to find it.

If possible, with source code and/or javadoc would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I was able to find it under [**javax:javaee-api**](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/javax/javaee-api/6.0/) along with the rest of java EE. There is also a [web version](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/javax/javaee-web-api/6.0/). I still cannot find an isolated version but I guess this is better than nothing. Also these versions don't have any JavaDocs.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Guide to Coping with Sun JARs](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-coping-with-sun-jars.html), you should be able to use either `javax.resource:connector` or `javax.resource:connector-api`.

Comment: Yes there I could find versions 1.0 and 1.5

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a 1.6 version anywhere on mvnrespository.com either. I ended up using Glassfish's spec: [org.glassfish.main.connectors:javax.resource:3.1.2.2](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.main.connectors/javax.resource/3.1.2.2)

The javax:javaee-api compiles OK, but broke my unit tests.